# Shiny - "ignoring" NA's in dropdown to show all of the previous dropdowns results

Tags: r, shiny

I have some data which looks like:

```
   zones         City regions sqft   price bedrooms baths
1  Zone1       Oxnard    RegB  893  179000        2  1.00
2  Zone1       Oxnard    RegB  989  180000        2  1.50
3  Zone1       Oxnard    RegB 1117  240000        3  1.75
4  Zone1       Oxnard    RegB 2203  408000        4  2.50
5  Zone2    SantaCruz    <NA> 1170  225000        2  2.00
6  Zone2    SantaCruz    <NA> 2846 1250000        4  3.00
7  Zone2    SantaCruz    <NA> 2600  899000        4  4.00
8  Zone3        Chino    RegC 1561  205000        4  2.50
9  Zone3        Chino    RegC 1400  209900        3  2.00
10 Zone3        Chino    RegC 2424  287500        4  3.00
11 Zone1 SantaClarita    RegA 1307  245000        3  2.00
12 Zone1 SantaClarita    RegA 1776  329999        4  2.50
13 Zone1 SantaClarita    RegA 2721  445990        5  3.00
14 Zone1 SantaClarita    RegA 3766  792000        4  3.00
15 Zone2    Clairmont    <NA>  959  229000        1  1.50
16 Zone2    Clairmont    <NA> 4400  799000        5  2.50
17 Zone2    Clairmont    <NA> 1600  460000        4  2.50
```

I have a complete data set for `zones`, `City` but not of the `regions` - i.e. there are some `NA`'s in this part.

The App currently looks like:

[image]

I want to create a filter for the data frame based on the 3 levels of the locations `zones`, `City` and `regions`. The problem occurs when I don't have information for the last level `regions` - it shows and NA. What I would like to have is when it reaches the last level and there is an `NA` in `Region` - I want to just show the previous levels results.

That is:

For `Zone2` --> `Clairmont` --> `NA`. I want to "ignore" this `NA` result and just show the result for `Clairmont` - i.e. the following:

```
15 Zone2    Clairmont    <NA>  959  229000        1  1.50
16 Zone2    Clairmont    <NA> 4400  799000        5  2.50
17 Zone2    Clairmont    <NA> 1600  460000        4  2.50
```

Currently it shows:

[image]

An empty table, but I want to it go back to the previous level and show the results for `Clairmont`.

App and Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(reactable)

##### Load the data

house = read.table("http://www.rossmanchance.com/iscam2/data/housing.txt", header = T, sep = "\t")

data = house %>% 
  filter(City == "SantaClarita" | City == "Oxnard" | City == "SantaCruz" | City == "Clairmont" | City == "Chino") %>% 
  mutate(
    zones = ifelse(City == "SantaClarita" | City == "Oxnard", "Zone1", ifelse(City == "SantaCruz" | City == "Clairmont", "Zone2", ifelse(City == "Chino", "Zone3", NA))),
    regions = ifelse(City == "SantaClarita", "RegA", ifelse(City == "Oxnard", "RegB", ifelse(City == "Chino", "RegC", NA)))
  ) %>% 
  relocate(zones, City, regions, .before = everything())

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  
  navbarPage("United",
             tabPanel("Property Search",
                      fluidRow(
                        column(3, selectInput("zoneSelect", label = "Zone", choices = c())),
                        column(3, selectInput("citySelect", label = "City", choices = c())),
                        column(3, selectInput("regionSelect", label = "Region", choices = c()))
                      ),
                      fluidRow(
                        column(12,
                               tags$h3("Filtered Properties"),
                               tableOutput('filteredDataOUT')
                        )
                      )
             )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ######
  observeEvent(input$zoneSelect,{
    updateSelectInput(
      session, 
      "citySelect", 
      choices = data  %>%  filter(zones == input$zoneSelect) %>% select(City) %>% arrange(City) %>% unique() %>% pull(City)
    )
  }) 
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(
      session, 
      "zoneSelect", 
      choices = data %>% arrange(zones) %>% select(zones) %>% unique() %>% pull(zones)
    )
  })
  
  
  ######
  observeEvent(input$citySelect,{
    updateSelectInput(
      session,
      "regionSelect",
      choices = data %>% filter(City == input$citySelect) %>% select(regions) %>% arrange(regions) %>% unique() %>% pull(regions)
    )
  })
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(
      session,
      "citySelect",
      choices = data %>% arrange(City) %>%  select(City) %>% unique() %>% pull(City))
  })

  ######### Filter the data
  
  filteredDATA = reactive(
    filteredData <- data %>% 
      filter(zones == input$zoneSelect & City == input$citySelect & regions == input$regionSelect)
  )
  output$filteredDataOUT <- renderTable(
    filteredDATA()
  )
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to just amend this in the source data? Do you want to keep the NA when filtering by other levels?

Comment: What do you mean by amend this in the source data? SOme `regions` have `NA` since the data does not go down as specific as other locations. I kind of just want to "ignore" the `NA` result if it appears